# Defining a ForeignKey field from the inverse/backwards side

Tags: python, django, model

I'm working with [django-paypal-adaptive](https://github.com/FundedByMe/django-paypal-adaptive), and I would like to create a relationship between one of my project's models (`Project`), and a model defined in the 3rd-party package (`Preapproval`).

I would love to do this:

```
class Preapproval(models.Model):
  ...
  project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

Thus, creating a many-`Preapproval`-to-one-`Project` relationship between the two models.

However, the `Preapproval` class is provided by the `django-paypal-adaptive`, so I cannot modify it.

How do I create a many-to-one relationship between `Preapproval` and `Project`?

Comment: I haven't used this extensively enough myself to actually call it an answer, but I believe you can add the FK dynamically using `contribute_to_class`. It takes some special effort but I think it should work. http://blog.jupo.org/2011/11/10/django-model-field-injection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and maintain your own branch of django-paypal-adaptive, and modify the Preapproval model to include your Project model.

You can take advantage of inheritance, defining a new model using the Preapproval model as the parent.

You can take advantage of composition, defining a new model that has a Foreign Key to the Preapproval model.

...just a few, but I am sure there are additional approaches.

Comment: We ended up going the composition route.  Created a new model called `ProjectPreapproval` that links `Projects` and `Preapprovals`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless the project allows you to override the `Preapproval` model in some way. You will need to fork the project or simply add the new model field to the 3rd party project in your `/lib/python/site-packages/.../` folder and migrate the model using South or something similar

Answer (score 0):

You could import Preapproval into your models and customize it

```
class MyPreapproval(Preapproval):
    ...
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but references to the original model are still floating around in the `django-paypal-adaptive` package, so it would only work as long as I don't use the 3rd-party package's views, tasks, etc.  Also, the database would contain 2 different preapproval tables, as the original `Preapproval` model is not [marked as abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).